# Add columns to a table that has more than 300K records

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a SpringBoot application which connects to a Postgres database present on Azure platform.

I added a new SQL script which Flyway will try to execute during the application deployment. Then the CPU usage of azure database does not change much but the number active connections goes very high and I see a lot of errors "Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException"

The SQL script I am trying to run is on a child table which has around 320K records:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME_1
    ADD COLUMN_5 VARCHAR(50),
    ADD COLUMN_6 BOOLEAN;
```

How can I make sure the script completes quick without causing so many new active connections. The script also seem to be taking more time to complete. I assumed 300K in a child table is not huge amount so the script will run very quick

Comment: That change should only take a few seconds (if at all) but it does require an exclusive lock. Maybe Flyway doesn't commit the change properly and that's why other session trying to use that table are blocked.

Comment: oh ok. My application runs in multiple instances (to prevent downtime during deployment) so probably when one instance is being deployed then the other app instance is creating too many locks on this table causing the `alter table` sql command to take so much time in flyway.

I will stop all app instances and then trigger the deployment and hopefully this will be then completed  smoothly (even though this causes downtime for the application a little)

Comment: Check your locks, this statement has to get a table lock. But when it get's the lock, it takes just halve a millisecond to alter the table like this because you don't write any data at all.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks. I stopped both the app instances and then the deployment completed successfully